# Add extension .PDF at the end of file name

Tags: vba

I have a column in the Excel sheet that contains the file names without the file extension. 
How can I with help off VBA add .PDF at the end of the file name, so that I get a column with the file names with .PDF extension?
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? and how this particular quetsion related to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cells with file names are in column A then you could write something like the following code...

```
Do Until Cells(x,1).value = ""
     Cells(x,1).value = Cells(x,1).value & ".PDF"
     x = x +1
Loop
```

This will loop through the column while there is a value within the cell and add ".PDF" to the end.

We will need more information if you'd like to do this with SQL, though.